# Firebase Redundancy/Failover - How does it work

Tags: firebase

I'm curious how redundant Firebase is?  When I write database to Firebase is it automatically replicated to multiple data centers/servers?

I noticed if I go to http://status.firebase.com/, there is a list of servers (?) called s-dal5-nss-XX.  Not sure what these exactly mean or how to find out which one of these your application resides on.

More information would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> how to find out which one of these your application resides on

From a discussion on the [Firebase mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/firebase-talk/yNP7AaHD65A):

> You can monitor https://.firebaseio.com/.settings/owner.json to find out what server is *currently* handling requests for your Firebase app. Note that whilst this is a method of getting the *current* hostname your Firebase is under, Firebase apps are not guaranteed to stay on the same server - configurations can (and do) change as we add or remove servers from rotation or load balance as necessary.